# Problem with edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener)

Tags: android, setonerrorlistener

I'm learning to use Android Studio and for my first App I'm doing a Tic Tac Toe. I have an activity where a player can write its name so it can be displayed later with his points. I want to implement the possibility to press ENTER to do it instead of having to press the Button "DONE" but I get the error "cannot resolve the symbol setOnKeyListener" (also with "event" and the two constants). What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.example.tictactoe;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;

public class login1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText playerOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playerOneLogin);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login1);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_player_one);
        final EditText playerOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playerOneLogin);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity2();
            }

        playerOne.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener) {
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                        startActivity2();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }

        });
    }
    public void startActivity2() {
        Intent intentPlayerOne = new Intent(this, login2.class);
        intentPlayerOne.putExtra("playerOne", playerOne.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intentPlayerOne);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you've missed some opening bracket for `OnKeyListener` constructor...

```
    playerOne.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() { // missing ( in here
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            startActivity2();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    // one additional unnecessary } was in here
});
```